# Why can't I connect to encrypted sqlite database file in C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, devart

I encrypt my sqlite database file and set its password to 123 as follows.

```
var conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=Encrypted.db;Version=3;");
conn.Open();
conn.ChangePassword("123");
```

I don't get an error when I try to connect to the encrypted sqlite database file as follows. So I think that there is no error in database encryption.

```
var conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=Encrypted.db;Password=123");
conn.Open();
```

I want to create a Devart LinqConnect Model for this database file. I tried two different ways to do this, as I share the screenshots below.

[image]

[image]

How do I create a Devart LinqConnect Model?

Comment: Did I ask the question in right place?

Comment: Make sure you replaced sqlite3.dll shipped with the provider installation with sqlite3.dll that supports CEROD: x86 version -> C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sqlite3.dll, 
x64 version -> C:\Windows\System32\sqlite3.dll.